# typscript how to modificate a object with a for cicle

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello I want to update a object with the next structure:

```
var searchBody: searchObject = {
  type: {
    name: {
      name: false,
      last_name: false,
      full_name: false,
      email: false,
      booking_id: false,
      phone_number: false,
    },
  },
  constrain: {
    name: {
      contain: false,
      equal_to: false,
      starts_by: false,
      ends_by: false,
    },
  },
  item: '',
};
```

With a for cicle and a conditional like this:

```
var n:number =0;
searchBy: string = '';
for (let key in searchBody.type.name) {
    //Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(searchBody.constrain.name, key)
    console.log(key)
    if (this.searchBy==n.toString()) {
        searchBody.constrain.name.key = true
    }
    n++
}
```

But Typescript mark the line inside the conditional as syntaxis error

Before I initialize my object I use the inteface to create each internal object in my main object, such as the next code:

```
interface searchByObject {
      name: boolean;
      last_name: boolean;
      full_name: boolean;
      email: boolean;
      booking_id: boolean;
      phone_number: boolean;
    }

    interface searchFilterObject{
      contain: boolean,
      equal_to: boolean,
      starts_by: boolean,
      ends_by: boolean,
    }

    interface searchBy {
      name: searchByObject;
    }

    interface searchFilter {
      name: searchFilterObject;
    }

    interface searchObject {
      type: searchBy;
      constrain: searchFilter;
      item: string;
    }
```

what is the logic that I have to use to create correctly my object and update its values, Thanks for your help c:

Comment: what's in the console. can u pls share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a property named `key`:

```
searchBody.constrain.name.key = true
```

If you want to access the property whose name is the **value** of `key` then you should do the following:

```
searchBody.constrain.name[key] = true
```

Here's more information about [Property accessors and the Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation)

### Edit

What you need to do is to explicitly tell typescript that `key` is in fact a valid key that exists in the `searchBody.constrain.name` object.

You can create a generic function which will tell typescript that using [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

```
const objectHas = <T>(object: T, key: string | number | symbol): key is keyof T => key in object;
```

We basically created a function that can get any object and a key and if the key exists in the object it will tell typescript that this value is indeed a valid key in the object.

then all you have to do if add this to your condition:

```
if (this.searchBy==n.toString() && objectHas(searchBody.constrain.name, key)) {
    searchBody.constrain.name[key] = true
}
```

Comment: Hello I tryed this but the terminal gave me this error:

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'searchFilterObject'.

Comment: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ name: boolean; last_name: boolean; full_name: boolean; email: boolean; booking_id: boolean; phone_number: boolean; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ name: boolean; last_name: boolean; full_name: boolean; email: boolean; booking_id: boolean; phone_number: boolean; }'.

81         searchBody.type.name[key] = true

Comment: Thank you so much for your explain it helped to me to understand how it works

Comment: im glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The property key dosn't exist.

```
searchBody.constrain.name.key = true
```

which property do you want change?

Comment: I know this property doesn't exist, but I'm trying to change any property, that depends of the condition that I've established